# change input text value and add new link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

on this [page](http://gioventu.nyc/collections/frontpage/products/karoshi-flannel-hunter?variant=1230655283), I'm want to change "sold out" on the button to "coming soon", and then have this link to a new page.

how would i do this?

HTML

```
<input type="submit" value="Sold Out" id="add" class="btn add-to-cart disabled" disabled="disabled" style="opacity: 0.5;">
```

Some Jquery

```
$(e.target).find(selectors.SUBMIT_ADD_TO_CART).attr('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
```

Comment: Please do the opposite, instead of asking "how would i do this?", tell us what is the problem with the code you are posting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, change the value to coming soon.

```
<input type="submit" value="Coming Soon!" id="add" class="btn add-to-cart disabled" disabled="disabled" style="opacity: 0.5;">
```

Next in your form change the action.

```
<form action="NEW PAGE HERE">
```

Did you mean you want to do this with Jquery..?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.add-to-cart').on('click', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.is(':disabled')) {
        $this.prop('disabled', false);
        $this.val('Coming Soon!');
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        /* do logic to go to other page if needed */
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

to change value for submit input

```
$('#add').val('Coming soon!');
```

or

```
$('#add').attr('value','Coming Soon!');
```